# Recording data from Android Kotlin API to the room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to save data to Room. There is a string, there is an int but there is also a List . I wonder if there is a way to save the listed structures in Room?

```
data class Model(
    var ranking: Int? = null,
    var team_name: String? = null,
    var coach: String? = null,
    var market_value: String? = null,
    var image: String? = null,
    var next_week_opponent: NextWeekOpponent? = null,
    var last_week_opponent: LastWeekOpponent? = null
)
```

Comment: You can use a typeconverter to convert the list into something else which ROOM can handle. You can for example make a JSON object out of the list and transform the JSON object into a string

Answer (score 0):

Room can handle collections and based on what value is passed, it returns single row ID or list of all the row IDs inserted. The response object needs be mapped with the entity.
For example response data class:

```
data class ApiResponse(
    val intValue: Int,
    val stringValue: String,
    val sources: List<SomeList>
)
```

```
val response = apiService.getSomeList()

appDatabase.someDummyDao.insertAll(response.someList)
```

Room can save/retrieve list.

```
  @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg list: SomeList): List<long>

  @Query("select * from some_table")
    fun getSavedList(): List<SomeList>
```